# Came to hate / had come to hate

Tags: verbs

I have a female friend and we used to have good feelings about each other, but we didn't end up becoming a couple. The problem was whenever we planed to meet at the time we were supposed to meet, she was always late for the appointment. So ...

1. I came to hate her.
2. I had come to hate her.

Number 2 is familiar with me, but I just want to know the difference between them.

Comment: Would _resent_ be a better word than _hate_? "Hate" seems like a strong word for chronic lateness.

Answer (score 2):

No. 1 is ambiguous, because "I came" can mean "I arrived" or "I went," as in, "I came here for a good cup of coffee." It almost makes it sound like you're trying to say, "I went to Incheon so I could hate her."

I would probably say,

> *I grew to dislike her.*

Comment: How about verb 'think'? I (grew to think / had grown to think) she was not a person that I like to be in a relationship with.

Comment: @jihoon - There are countless ways to say it, not just one or two. That's the beauty of English.

Comment: Yes!! I got it!! and I think you could be a korean seeing as you know Incheon. Or have you ever been here in Korea?

Comment: I've never been to Korea, but I'm smart enough to realize that I shouldn't always use cities like Boston or Philadelphia when giving examples to English learners. :^) Picking a different city might help the learner contexualize the example better.

Comment: @jihoon "I had grown to think we were `incompatible`" is a good way to say this.

Comment: @DJ - Excellent word suggestion! You can shorten that, too, by saying, "We became incompatible."